# Speed Comparison decodeResource vs createBitmap

Tags: android, performance, bitmap

For a current project I need to know which method is faster:

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,config)
```

or

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),id)
```

thanks for your support

Comment: When you ran your own benchmarks to determine whether it is faster for *your* resources, what did you learn?

Comment: For me it seems that decoding a resource is faster. But this may not be the case on every android device...Is there no general statement like "decoding a resource is always faster than creating a new bitmap"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually ask questions on sites like this because I hope there are some people who may have experienced the same situation or asked themselves the same question as I do. But more and more i recognised that simple questions like the above one,are obviously not wanted here.

The answer for my question is:

> Loading Bitmaps is not as fast( and thus efficient) as creating a new one

Thanks for the great help and suggestions

Comment: I recommend deleting this question. There is no valuable information in here, and the answer seems not be an empirical benchmark or documentation quote.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted your answer but it's important to note that these methods are not interchangeable, as some people may assume from the question.
AFAIK, `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` is used to instantiate a Bitmap from a resource (e.g. a .png or .xml in the drawable directory),
While `Bitmap.createBitmap()` is used to instantiate a brand enter code herenew Bitmap (basically from primitives such as float etc), so i don't see how they could be interchangeably used, and hope i saved future readers from scratching their heads a little.